# How do I force Ubuntu to use amd64, not i386

Tags: apt, package-management

I have a 1 year old desktop, with 64-bit features (which is quite normal ?). It's running Ubuntu. When I installed this, I ensured I had an amd64 kernel (see below), and C lib. I have added random software over the last year.

APT is really keen to give me 32-bit packages.  I would like a switch/config for `apt-get` that says force 64-bit if package is available.  I know how to do this on a per package basis, but need to get *everything* to 64-bit.

Any suggestions?
REBRIEF: My problem is that I seem to be unable to use standard features of the package manager ~ **correct hardware targeting**. If the best solution is to rebuild the box, then that is what I will do.

```
$ uname -a
Linux meow 4.4.0-36-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:01:55 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
amd64

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

 $ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
 processor       : 0
 vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
 cpu family      : 6
 model           : 61
 model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
 stepping        : 4
 microcode       : 0x16
 cpu MHz         : 2357.343
 cache size      : 4096 KB
 physical id     : 0
 siblings        : 4
 core id         : 0
 cpu cores       : 2
 apicid          : 0
 initial apicid  : 0
 fpu             : yes
 fpu_exception   : yes
 cpuid level     : 20
 wp              : yes
 flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdseed adx smap xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
 bugs            :
 bogomips        : 4788.91
 clflush size    : 64
 cache_alignment : 64
 address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
 power management:
```

As a last gasp, I could `apt list --installed`, and regex-fu to mention amd64, then upgrade every package, but this is a not clean solution.

My current focus point is python3:i386 not being python3:amd64.

EDIT responding to @bodhi.zazen:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install python3:amd64
 [sudo] password for user: 
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
 The following packages have unmet dependencies.
  python3 : Conflicts: python3:amd64 but 3.5.1-3 is to be installed
```

(I know that there is a python:amd64, as its a requirement for other tools)

EDIT responding to @guiverc

```
 $ dpkg -l python3
 Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
 ||/ Name                   Version          Architecture     Description
 +++-======================-================-================-==================================================
 ii  python3                3.5.1-3          i386             interactive high-level object-oriented language (d
 user@meow:~$ 
 user@meow:~$ aptitude why python3
 i   indicator-cpufreq Depends python3
```

EDIT response to @ravery 
Ok, that would make more sense, from an OS design perspective.
If you post as a response, I will take that as an answer

Comment: What makes you think you have 32 bit packages installed ? Nothing you posted indicates anything but 64 bit.

Comment: why do you think python3 is x86, did you `dpkg -l python3`?    try `aptitude why python3` to list why it (or others) was installed.  maybe you installed one 32bit package which pulled in more needed to run it.  (pe: i'm using package python3 only as example as you mentioned it...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures 
amd64
```

This states that you installed your system as 32-bit, since 64-bit is "foreign" to your system architecture.
This is why apt keeps giving you 32-bit packages.

The fix is to reinstall using the 64-bit image.